# How to show scroll indicator, Scrollbar on certain position of the screen? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

Is there a way in Flutter to show a scroll indicator only on a specific widget?

For instance, I have the following widget tree

```
CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                sliverAppBar(),
                sliverToBoxAdapter(), // horizontal list view
                SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate()) // show scrollbar only for this widget
              ],
            ),
```

Here is a demonstration of the iOS app Telegram, I have something similar in my app, notice when the header collapses a gray scroll indicator shows up.

Any idea on how to implement this behavior will be highly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scrollable List](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) which provide you the **nice** way to fulfill your requirements